# Eclipse Java config missing path? Cannot resolve BitMask

Tags: java, eclipse, bitmask

I'm new to Java in Eclipse.

I've built and run my Hello World application and am exploring how to add additional variables.
I'm trying to create a BitMask variable but I'm getting the error: BitMask cannot be resoved to type.

My main class looks like this:

```
import org.eclipse.core.internal.utils;

public class DNAMain {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    BitMask bm = new BitMask();

}

}
```

My assumption is that I have not included a specific library but I can't seem to determine which one or how to do it.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your import statement to be:

`import org.eclipse.core.internal.utils.BitMask;`

In the future, if you want help with specific classes, I would recommend looking at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).  In this case that class seems to be Eclipse-specific, so you might need to just Google "javadocs "

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it hasn't helped.

I get: The import org.eclipse cannot be resolved

...which leads me back to the assumption I have a config issue that I don't know how to resolve.

Comment: That seems more like a question for Eclipse support then.  It's possible the package was never installed.